# GWT: working with JsDate and Java Date

Tags: javascript, gwt, date, overlay, jsni

In my overlays I wrap a JavaScript Date object in a JsDate:

```
public final native JsDate getDueDate() /*-{
    return this["dueDate"];
}-*/;
```

However when I want to use that date in a widget, say a DateBox, I
need to set the value as a Java Date. I could create a Java Date from my
JsDate but I believe that adds some overhead.

```
Date javaDate = new Date(jsDate.getTime());
```

Is there a cleaner way of achieving this? What is the best way to convert a JsDate object to a Java Date object and vice-versa?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Jason's code doesn't work for me since `getDueDateNative().getTime()` returns a `double` and not a `long`. Therefore you have also to cast the value: `return new Date((long) getDueDateNative().getTime());`

Answer (score 3):

GWT's `Date` implementation uses `JsDate` under the covers so there should be no meaningful performance penalty at all. To make things easier for consumers of the type change your overlay to return `Date`s instead of `JsDate`s:

```
public final Date getDueDate() {
  return new Date(getDueDateNative().getTime());
}

private final static JsDate getDueDateNative() /*-{
  return this["dueDate"];
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. After looking to the generated Javascript I have found that the compiler does not eliminate the intermediate JsDate.

Comment: Yeah, since the emulated Date isn't an overlay type there will always be at least two native JS dates - the one in your overlay type and the one in the Date object. That said, I don't think having an extra JS date around is going to materially affect your application so my recommendation w.r.t. modifying the getDueDate() method on your overlay type stands.